# How to fix dropdown menu not working in Firefox quantum

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, firefox-quantum

I have a dropdown menu on my website which is not working with Firefox Quantum but works when using Safari or Chrome. Here is a link to the page, it is the "select a size for your print" which is not working: https://www.alaincombemorel.com/prints-for-sale/tre-cime-di-lavaredo-2/
Is it related to some coding errors on my side or is it some settings within firefox that prevent the menu from working?

I have tried to whitelist the website within Firefox parameters (popup, cookies, etc..) not to prevail

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("select").change(function() {
    var selected = jQuery(this).find('option:selected');
    jQuery('#foo').html(selected.data('foo'));
  }).change();
  jQuery("select").change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '1') {
      jQuery('#small').show();
      jQuery('#medium').hide();
      jQuery('#large').hide();
    } else if (jQuery(this).val() == '2') {
      jQuery('#small').hide();
      jQuery('#medium').show();
      jQuery('#large').hide();
    } else if (jQuery(this).val() == '3') {
      jQuery('#small').hide();
      jQuery('#medium').hide();
      jQuery('#large').show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#small').hide();
      jQuery('#medium').hide();
      jQuery('#large').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here is the code I am using:

<div class="print-order">
  <table class="print-select">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <h6>Select a size for your print:</h6>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select id="select">
          <option value="0" data-foo="">Select:</option>
                    <option value="1" data-foo=" price: 100€ ">24x30cm</option>
                  <option value="2" data-foo=" price: 150€ ">30x40cm</option>
                  <option value="3" data-foo=" price: 200€ ">40x50cm</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- print order -->
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - Please change the html pane to contain HTML instead of PHP (view-source)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the culprit: it was a plugin (Wp-Copyright pro) I had which was blocking the dropdown menu.
I disabled the plugin and now everything is working.
Regards
Alain